# Glassfish Server Library not available in Eclipse Kepler?

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, buildpath

I'm setting up a new dev machine with Eclipse Kepler to deploy on a Glassfish 3.1.2.2 instance.

When I go to

```
project properties > java build path > libraries > add library > server runtime
```

**There is no option to add the Glassfish server libraries.**

Some other notes of what I've done (whether they help or not...):

- Manually installed GF
- Installed OEPE for Juno
- GF Server already added
- GF Server starts / stops no problem (from Eclipse)

I pretty much had the same setup on my other machine with the exception that I used Juno instead of Kepler (however, I tried the above with a fresh Juno install as well).  That machine has everything working but was set up a while ago.  From what I understand, there has been a lot of changes with GF, Eclipse plugins and such: https://blogs.oracle.com/piotrik/entry/glassfish_3_1_2_2  .  So perhaps it's still under works and not fully ready?

In the meantime, I created a User Library with the Glassfish jar files from the Modules folder.  Not the ideal solution but it works for now.

However, I still rather have the "cleaner" method of adding a Server Runtime instead.  Ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

See the thread [GlassFish Tools does not provide a Server Runtime for Java Build Path](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2552592) in the Oracle forum.

Summary: They no longer provide a "Server Runtime" for plain Java projects. Instead, the project needs to be a faceted project and have a target runtime.

To configure this, do the following:

1. Go to the project properties > *Project Facets*
2. If necessary, click on *Convert to faceted form...*
3. In the *Runtimes* tab, select *GlassFish 3.1*

In case you need to export the GlassFish libraries to dependent projects, also do the following:

1. In *Project Facets* properties, select *Utility Module* and click *Apply*
2. In *Java Build Path* > *Order and Export*, select *GlassFish System Libraries*

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thanks for the info update and a clean solution.

Answer (score 3):

Someone has reported this issue in the Oracle Glassfish Tools forum. A fix will be included in the next release, which "will be out before too long".

See https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2552592

I ended up installing "GlassFish Tools for Indigo" from Help > Eclipse Marketplace...

Comment: Can you do that with Eclipse Kepler ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in Eclipse Kepler / Glassfish Server Tools.

You can try the following:

Add this in your projects .classpath file:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.lib.system">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="jst.web"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

Update the file `YOUR_PROJECT/.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml` to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faceted-project>
  <runtime name="GlassFish 3.1"/>  <-- Insert the name of your Glassfish Runtime in Eclipse here 
  <fixed facet="jst.web"/>
  <fixed facet="java"/>
  <fixed facet="wst.jsdt.web"/>
  <installed facet="java" version="1.7"/>
  <installed facet="jst.web" version="3.0"/>
  <installed facet="glassfish.web" version="3.1"/> <-- Glassfish Version here
  <installed facet="wst.jsdt.web" version="1.0"/>
</faceted-project>
```

You have to choose the appropriate runtime name which you defined in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Goto Project Properties > Project Facets > Under the tabs 'Runtimes' > Select the glass fish server and click on Apply. This will setup the GF Java EE libraries in the build path.