# How install Glassfish server for Eclipse Oxygen?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, glassfish

I have installed Glassfish Tools via marketplace but Glassfish server does not appear in the selection list when creating a new server.

Note:  I have added `-vm` parameter in the `eclipse.ini` and set `Java JDK 8` as default runtime for my workspace. Also `Download additional server adapters` link button in server creation windows is not present.

Comment: How did you add the `-vm` parameter ?
Looks like someone had the same issue here, for eclipse Kepler : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204096/glassfish-server-library-not-available-in-eclipse-kepler

Answer (score 0):

1. *Right Click Server tab --> New --> Server*
2. *Oracle --> Glassfish Tools --> Click Next --> Accept the licence agreement 
   --> Click Finish*

It will take several time.

Restart the Eclipse IDE

[Download ogs-3.1.2.zip File and Extract where you want in your machine](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/glassfish/downloads/java-archive-downloads-glassfish-419424.html#ogs-3.1.2-oth-JPR)

3. *Again Right click server tab --> New --> Server --> Glassfish -->Glassfish **Click Next***
4. *Add the glassfish installed location in your local machine to **Glassfish Location***

Example :

- **Glassfish location > C:\glassfish3\glassfish**
- **Java location      > C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80**

[image]

5. *Add the glassfish server domain directory.*

   Example :

   - **Domain path > C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1**

[image]

6. *Finish*
7. *Right click on glassfish and click start.*